# Where does IntelliJ IDEA keep local history files?

Tags: intellij-idea, revision-history

My company has a policy about keeping source code in encrypted storage when on local developer machines. Where does IntelliJ IDEA keep the copy of the code changes that is used to drive its [local history feature](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/local_history.html)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Local history file location:

*(Answer updated to show new locations as they changed in v2020.1)*

They are stored in `${idea.system.path}/LocalHistory/`. See the [Directories used by the IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html) page in the user guide (and this legacy IDEA [document](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-181)) for the location of the IntelliJ IDEA `idea.system.path` directory on various platforms. **The default locations changed in 2020.1.** See the above guide for info if using an older version. Also note the locations can change based on overrides you may have made.

**The *defaults* for the `system` directory for 2020.1 and later are:**

- Windows:

  - `%LOCALAPPDATA%\JetBrains\<product><version>`
  - Example: `C:\Users\Snoopy\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.1`
- Mac:

  - `~/Library/Caches/JetBrains/<product><version>`
  - Example: `~/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.1`
- Linux:

  - `~/.cache/JetBrains/<product><version>`
  - Example: `~/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2022.1`

### Turning off local history

As a side note, if you want to turn local history off, you can do so in the maintenance registry. On Windows/Linux, you can access it via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>, or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> on Mac. Select "**Registry**" from the popup. In the registry dialog, find the entry `localHistory.daysToKeep` and set it to zero. (I've never actually tried setting it to zero, but I am assuming it would work for you.)

Comment: Shortcut also works in Linux. Presumably, Ctrl can be swapped for ⌘ on OS X.

Comment: Note that, although this is still correct, where IDEA keeps the `System` directory changed from 2019.3 to 2020.1, and upgrades will import the settings from the old location: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html#default-dirs

Answer (score 4):

After the information provided by **Javaru**. For example, **PyCharm** saves the *Local History* at:

```
~/Library/Caches/PyCharm2017.1/LocalHistory
```

More information:
[Project and IDE Settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/15.0/project-and-ide-settings.html), 
[Directories used by the IDE to store settings, caches, plugins and logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519)

Answer (score 2):

On my Windows machine, local history is kept in this folder:

```
C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.3\LocalHistory
```

Answer (score 0):

On my Linux device, (Android Studio 4.1 RC 3 under Ubuntu 20.04.1), local history is kept in this folder.

```
/home/[user]/.cache/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/LocalHistory
```

With every new release of Android Studio, I have at some time or another attempted to flush all source code change history using *Invalidate Caches / Restart* but this has always failed.

After many years I have concluded that despite various assertions to the contrary, the only way to achieve this is to trash the **LocalHistory** folder along with its containees **changes.storageData** and **changes.storageRecordIndex**.