# Where does PhpStorm store the Local History?

Tags: phpstorm

PhpStorm keeps a [Local History](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/local-history.html) of all the files.

Does anyone know where these files are stored?

Comment: A local history like for "Undo" button ? Can you be more precise about this local history ?

Comment: @Mr.Blackus Read this for what "Local History" is: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Local+History+in+PhpStorm

Comment: @LazyOne But, it's about VCS no ? Isn't it about git, subversion or other VCS software ? If so, storing method depends on VCS used.

Comment: @Mr.Blackus No, it's not related to VCS. PHPStorm keep all modification in his own local history, even if you don't use a VCS software.

Comment: @Mr.Blackus Local History is a **simple local VCS** -- it's not a proper VCS -- it's just keeps diff copies of your project files (file must be under 1MB in size) and it makes new diff after each Save. This is different to what proper VCS does where you need to Submit/Push/Merge etc. If you want -- it's like better (much better) Undo .. which can work as group undo (revert multiple files (e.g. afetr global find/replace) in one click) but works only with Save points.

Comment: Similar question for IntelliJ IDEA: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22567420/where-does-intellij-idea-keep-local-history-files

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Local History is stored together with other index/cache files** -- you will not be able to read it yourself if you wanted to copy/back up it separately -- it's linked to your current files and will get removed if you use `File | Invalidate Caches..` for example.

**Exact location** varies on OS: [Directories used by the IDE to store settings, caches, plugins and logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs).

On Windows 7 for PhpStorm v8 it will typically be in `C:\Users\USERNAME\.WebIde80\system\LocalHistory` folder.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac, the files are stored at `$HOME/Library/Caches/JetBrains/<ide-name>/LocalHistory` where `<ide-name>` will be whatever your specific JetBrains install is + the version. In my case, it's `PhpStorm2023.1`.